# Using Python and simple salesforce with parameters “Bind variables only allowed in Apex code”

Tags: soql, python, bind-variable

```
dict = sf.query("SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,Email FROM Contact WHERE Id=:cid")
```

`cid` is a variable defined by myself. I wonder how to use the simple query function to select the field.
Any response will be helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to explicitly send a `String` of the query to SOQL from python, replace variable binding with concrete values and concatenations of string

```
ict = sf.query("SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,Email FROM Contact WHERE Id='" + cid + "'")
```

This is exactly the same, as [Dynamic SOQL in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm)